# найти максимум в строках датафрейма в конкретных столбцах и записать название столбца в ячейку

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

есть датафрейм вида:

| index | data | x1 | x2 | x3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | st1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  |
| B | st2 | 3 | 7 | 6 |  |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |  |
| Z | st500 | 1 | 0 | 8 |  |

как мне красиво найти максимум по каждой строке A-Z среди столбцов x1-x3  и в столбец Result занести название столбца, в котором найден максимум.

Comment: В вопросе нужно приводить воспроизводимый пример данных. И не плохо бы приводить свои попытки решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При df:

```
    data  x1  x2  x3
A   str1  76  41  33
B   str2  18  82  28
C   str3  62  33  48
.  .  .
X  str24  57  66   1
Y  str25  10  86  24
Z  str26  50  74  58
```

воспользуйтесь методом `idxmax` с указанием нужной `axis`:

```
df["Result"] = df[["x1", "x2", "x3"]].idxmax(axis=1)
```

результат будет таким:

```
    data  x1  x2  x3 Result
A   str1  76  41  33     x1
B   str2  18  82  28     x2
C   str3  62  33  48     x1
.  .  .
X  str24  57  66   1     x2
Y  str25  10  86  24     x2
Z  str26  50  74  58     x2
```

Дополнение:

Если вам нужно найти максимумы в числовых столбцах, а их количество не известно или может меняться, есть более универсальный способ:

```
import numpy as np

df["Result"] = df.select_dtypes(np.number).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Результат, понятно, будет тот же.

Comment: я так понимаю, что строка: df["Result"] = df.select_dtypes(np.number).idxmax(axis=1) выбирает только те столбцы где есть числа, но это не совсем подходит.  Что если названия столбцов, по которым мне надо искать максимум, у меня есть в списке list1 ?

Comment: вот так все заработало:
list1 = ['x1', 'x2']
common_cols = list(set(df.columns).intersection(set(list1)))
df["Result"] = df[common_cols].idxmax(axis=1)

Comment: я вам в первом варианте указал, как решить, если у вас есть список колонок. Если названия столбцов у вас есть в списке list1, то не изобретайте велосипед: `df["Result"] = df[list1].idxmax(axis=1)`